# Как передать в ответе post-запросу несколько ответов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Мне нужно передать порядка 8 ответов сервера клиенту, если для каждого делать свой post-запрос - код получится ну СЛИИИШКОМ большим, поэтому хочу узнать, возможно ли передать сразу несколько ответов от сервера клиенту через post-запрос и если да, то как?

Comment: "если да, то как" - как json-кодированный массив данных

Comment: http работает по принципу туда-сюда. Либо в один ответ пихайте несколько объектов сразу, либо websocket'ы используйте.

Comment: Передать все ответы в массиве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Восемь ответов нет, но можете передать один большой который будет содержать ответы из всех восьми, только учтите что скорее всего вы получите просадку по перфомансу, но это не точно, зависит от ресурсоемкости операций для получения данных для ответа и размер собственно самого ответа